# Swift setAnimationTransition with custom animation

Tags: ios, swift, pushviewcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm studying Swift and I want to create a side menu, with no lib. I'm used to android, but never developed in Obj-C, so here is what I want to do:

[image: sample animated transition]

So, I'm using a navigation controller, and a trick from another question to begin on the "detail view". Digging a little on Google, I found this code:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.75, animations: { () -> Void in
    UIView.setAnimationCurve(UIViewAnimationCurve.EaseInOut)
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(mapViewControllerObejct!, animated: false)
    UIView.setAnimationTransition(UIViewAnimationTransition.FlipFromLeft, forView: self.navigationController!.view!, cache: false)
})
```

And I found [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/custom-view-controller-transitions-tutorial/) that explains how to create custom transitions. The problem is that they use Segues, and I use NavigationController to call the other view.

I want to know how to use a custom transition like the ones described by AppCoda with `pushViewController` instead of a segue.